# C# Outlook VSTO Entry Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

I am creating my own custom journal entry form, and one of the things that I would like to have is a drop down menu (like the one in the picture) but have it automatically populated by an entry type list (if it exists). Is there some Outlook object that contains entry types or a list of these that I can tell a dropdown to populate with?

I looked at the `JournalItem` API, but couldn't find anything on this. Not really sure where to look for these. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866277.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `JournalItem.Type` property. The list of available entries is hardcoded.